# Multipy usage of Cache-Control header

Tags: http-headers, cache-control

Is it possible to add more than once the `Cache-Control` header?
What setting will be effective if I see the following headers?

```
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, private
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

Is setting accumulative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [RFC 7230, 3.2.2. Field Order](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.2.2):

> A recipient MAY combine multiple header fields with the same field
> name into one "field-name: field-value" pair, without changing the
> semantics of the message, by appending each subsequent field value to
> the combined field value in order, separated by a comma.

This request is treated the same as:

```
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, private, no-cache
```

Note that [in RFC 7234, 4.2.1.  Calculating Freshness Lifetime](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-4.2.1):

> When there is more than one value present for a given directive
> (e.g., two Expires header fields, multiple Cache-Control: max-age
> directives), the directive's value is considered invalid.

I believe the example you give is valid but, for example:

```
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Cache-Control: max-age=3600
```

would be invalid.